# Enable metrics for endpoints in Spring micrometer

Tags: java, spring, metrics, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm migrating Java Spring project from java 8 to java 11. So I need to replace dropwizard metrics with micrometer. Dropwizard metrics were recording statuses and responses when hitting certain endpoint.
E.g: endpoint `localhost:8080/my_service/v1/api/some/endpoint`  -->> and metrics recorded
`metrics.prefix.counter.status.200.v1.api.some.endpoint`
`metrics.prefix.gauge.response.v1.api.some.endpoint`

Is there a way to anable the same in Micrometer? I'm aware there is `@Counted` annotation, but for some reason it doesn't work. (I'm putting it on endpoint method).

My propertries file (metrics-related values only):

```
management.metrics.export.statsd.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.statsd.host=****
management.metrics.export.statsd.port=8125
management.metrics.export.statsd.flavor=etsy
management.metrics.export.statsd.prefix=metrics.prefix
management.metrics.export.statsd.polling-frequency=10s
management.metrics.web.server.auto-time-requests=:true
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to see those metrics if you are using Spring to create your endpoint (mvc or webflux).

You should see `http.server.requests` which has all the details (as tags) that you have in the name above (uri, status) and more.

In order to make `@Counted` (and/or `@Timed` work) you need to create a `CountedAspect` (and/or `TimedAspect`) `@Bean` but as I said, if you only use it on the controlled, they are not needed.